# Cascading actions not rendering

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I'm doing something like this:

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

export default class DataStore {
  @observable pageData:object

  @action fetch() {
    superagent.get(url1)
    .send('got url 1', action((err, results) => {
      if (err)
        return;
      this.pageData = this.pageData || {};
      this.pageData.urlData1 = results;
      this.fetchAnother();
    }));
  }

  @action fetchAnother() {
    superagent.get(url2)
    .send('got url 2', action((err, results) => {
      if (err)
        return;
      this.pageData = this.pageData || {};
      this.pageData.urlData2 = results;
    }));
  }
}
```

These actions are separate because sometimes `fetchAnother` is called by itself.

I inject the store into my React component class. When `fetch` is called, the first async callback wrapped in `action` updates the page, and `urlData1` is rendered. Then the 2nd callback in `fetchAnother` is called and executes, but does not render, and `urlData2` will only show if I force a re-render in some other way. Why, and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

MobX doesn't support dynamically adding fields to plain objects. Either use an observable map or initialize the fields upfront:

```
pageData = { urlData1: null, urlData2: null }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "observable map"?

Comment: Even if I do something like add `@observable random:number` to the parent, and set `this.random = Math.random();` at the end of `fetchAnother`, it does not re-render when called from `fetch`.

Comment: Is your react component decorated with `@observer`?